# Указательная частица ТО в неопределенных местоимениях и наречиях

Tags: словообразование

Неопределенное наречие "как-то" и союз "как то" имеют разный смысл. Действительно, что общего между значением неопределенности в наречии и УКАЗАНИЕМ на дальнейшее перечисление в предложении с однородными членами!

Значение УКАЗАТЕЛЬНОСТИ частица ТО имеет и в других словах, например: в наречии "вообще-то", если оно описывает ситуацию "то - вообще, а это - в частности", или в предложении "он-то знает, а я нет". (Кстати, в приведенных примерах используется дефисное написание частицы, так что союз "как то" тоже мог бы писаться через дефис, но дефисная форма не используется в союзах).

Но почему УКАЗАТЕЛЬНАЯ частица ТО стала использоваться для образования слов с НЕОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫМ значением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом конкретном различении (*как тО* - *кАк-то*, *будь тО* - *бУдто*), важную роль играет ударение. Плюс перемена общей утвердительной интонации на интонацию неопределенную или вопросительную.
Поэтому возникает смысл не указательно-утвердительный, а наоборот.
*Неважно, когда ты пошел в отпуск, будь тО зима или лето.*
*Настроение было праздничным, будто Новый Год наступил.*
Добавим соображений.
"Вопросительные" слова - где, как, когда, зачем и др. - при добавлении к ним указательной частицы **-то** меняют свой вопросительный смысл на несколько общий, неопределенный.
Примеры.
*Где-то в Канаде*. Где? тО в Канаде... *Когда-то давно*. Когда? тО давно.
Вопрос и указательность нейтрализуют друг друга и дают в сумме неопределенность.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в сравнительном союзе БУДТО указательное значение частицы ТО сохраняется, она указывает на предмет сравнения. А вот, к примеру, в наречиях ГДЕ-ТО, КОГДА-ТО указательность не чувствуется: Где-то вдали слышны голоса. Когда-то мы были друзьями. Может быть, это ВОПРОС БЕЗ ОТВЕТА, который вследствие этого приобретает неопределенность (то когда мы были друзьями)?

Answer (score 1):

София, подробнее здесь: [Чем "как-то" отличается от "как то"](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.52)

Comment: Серж, я читала этот материал, но ответа там не нашла. А Вы можете в двух словах сказать, как указательное значение преобразуется в неопределенное?

Comment: В статье лишь говорится, что ни по происхождению, ни по значению местоименное слово "как-то" не связано с союзом как то. Союз как то близок по значению к сочетанием "как такое", "как это". Как получилось, что они совпали, в статье не говорится. Наверное, омонимия, возникнувшая в процессе развития языка. Я не обладаю серьезными лингвистическими исследованиями, но, на мой взгляд, союз "как то'' возник от сочетания "как это" , а потом в процессе развития "э" редуцировалось и получилось как то. Вы прекрасно знаете, что такое в языке бывает часто.

Comment: По-моему, с союзом всё ясно. Например: "На столе навалены груды разных вещей, как то: старинные камзолы,кафтаны,мундиры". "Как то" - это "как то, что будет перечислено, именно...". Здесь сравнительный союз КАК и местоимение ТО (повтор обобщающего слова).

Answer (score 0):

> > Но почему УКАЗАТЕЛЬНАЯ частица ТО стала использоваться для образования слов с НЕОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫМ значением?

Вы уверены, что она, указательная частица, именно СТАЛА использоваться? Не использовалась, не использовалась, была только указательной, а потом СТАЛА использоваться для образования слов с неопределенным значением?

Может быть, это и вовсе два не связанных между собой слова.

Comment: Может быть. У Вас есть какая-то информация на этот счет?

Comment: Нету. Но могу добавить, что в наречии "вообще-то" трудно разглядеть "указательность". А также в словах типа "я-то". Здесь это усиление, а не неопределенность, как в "когда-то". А пишется одинаково — через дефис.

Comment: Здесь, скорее,  не усилительное, а выделительное значение, но оно строится на указательном значении, так как часто подразумевается продолжение темы с указанием на две ситуации: я-то, но он-то. Есть еще восклицательные предложения: ночь-то какая! Здесь тоже указание: то ночь какая!

Comment: >> ночь-то какая! Здесь тоже указание: то ночь какая!

Из пальца же высасываете... "То ночь какая" — это что?

Comment: И про наречие вообще-то. Вот пример: Я вообще люблю читать. - Я вообще-то люблю читать, но сейчас нет возможности. Мне кажется, что здесь тоже имеет место указание на две ситуации.

Comment: Да, две ситуации. Во втором случае "вообще-то" — вводное слово (в значении "вообще говоря") и должно быть обособлено.

Comment: Niemand, вот Вы не поверите, но в книге "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" слово "вообще-то" при противопоставлении считается частицей и не обособляется. И по поводу "ночь-то какая", указательная там частица или еще какая? Нет ли у Вас какой-нибудь версии/гипотезы?

Comment: Ладно, по поводу "вообще-то" согласен, но тогда ее надо считать чистым синонимом "вообще". А "Ночь-то какая!" — не указательная, а усилительная частица. Синоним к "Какая ночь!"